# Convertir Double a String con separador decimal con coma

Tags: java, double, decimal

Tengo un Doble, ejemplo: 3.5
Necesito pasarlo a String de forma que el separador decimal en vez de ser punto sea coma, alguna forma eficiente de hacer este cambio?

Lo necesito para hacer una exportación con apache POI y que en el excel al que se exporta los decimales los muestre con separador decimal con coma en vez de con punto.

Answer (score 1):

Sí se puede realizar. Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo he hecho.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
      myFormat.setGroupingUsed(true);
      double[] numbers = {1.16763, 443330, 3, 517827.17};

      System.out.println("adding commas to number in Java using NumberFormat class");
      for (double d : numbers) {
           System.out.println(myFormat.format(d));
      }
   }
}
```

Con `NumberFormat` puedes darle el formato según el país. Por lo tanto te saldrán los decimales con comas y los millares con puntos.